# Do we need `if __name__ == '__main__': unittest.main()` in every unit tests file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pipeline, python-unittest

I have written a couple of unit tests (in multiple Python files), I'm not sure if I should include the line below in every unit test file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

If I try to run the unit tests without this two lines (for example in Pycharm), the unit tests will still be executed, so why we need these two lines?
My goal is to package these tests and run them on a pipeline, so do I need to include those two lines in every file? Thanks.

Comment: You don't _need_ to add them, unless you want to be able to e.g. `python3 testfile.py` and have that run the tests.

Comment: In fact, *unless* you use `python3 testfile.py` or similar, the code is equivalent to `if False: pass`, and can be omitted. PyCharm is *importing* the file and executing the tests itself, i.e., PyCharm is playing the part of `unittest.main()`.

Comment: so I don't need to include these two lines in any of the unit test file, when I package the tests and deploy it to the pipeline, the tests should be executed right?

Comment: You don't mention what that pipeline is. But tools like pytest will automatically [find and run tests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/goodpractices.html#test-discovery) (provided the tests are decently named); that already gives you a simple style of pipeline (in particular when combined with continuous integration).

Comment: I was going to add an answer but it was basically what @jonrsharpe already entered as a comment!